# Компилятор поломался :(

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++, stl, динамическое-программирование

Есть такой код в одном из методов шаблонной структры:

```
            if constexpr (std::is_move_assignable<T>::value) {
                Data[Size] = std::move(value);
            } else {
                Data[Size] = value;
            }
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

/home/oem/Desktop/uuu/main.cpp:70:28: error: use of deleted function ‘MinimalObj& MinimalObj::operator=(const MinimalObj&)’   70 |                 Data[Size] = std::move(value);

Как сделать чтобы он не лез в первый клоз?

Вот откуда запускаю:

```
struct MinimalObj {
    int id;  // NOLINT(misc-non-private-member-variables-in-classes)

    // Draft check for leaks, double-frees and non-inits.
    // NOLINTNEXTLINE(misc-non-private-member-variables-in-classes)
    std::string data = std::string(500U, 'x');

    explicit MinimalObj(int id_) : id(id_) {}
    MinimalObj(MinimalObj &&) = default;
    MinimalObj &operator=(MinimalObj &&) = default;

    MinimalObj(const MinimalObj &) = delete;
    MinimalObj &operator=(const MinimalObj &) = delete;

    ~MinimalObj() = default;
};

signed main() {
    lab_07::vector<MinimalObj> v;
    MinimalObj a{5};
    v.push_back(a);
    v.pop_back();
    if (v.size() == 4) {}
    if (v.empty()) {}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Harry мне нужно чтобы структура которую я пишу от разных типов работала. включая такие

Comment: Вроде компилируется: https://ideone.com/9sWbsD Как воспроизвести?

Comment: Кстати, метка `шаблоны` - это о шаблонах проектирования, в описании же написано...

Comment: @Harry https://ideone.com/MydUWJ а у меня нет. в чем разница?

Comment: Как минимум вы его компилируете как Java...

Comment: У вас проблема в том, что параметр `push_back` - `const T&` - но какое же может быть `move`  для константной ссылки?... :(

Comment: @Harry это неважно, на ноуте плюсами компилирую - тоже не работает

Comment: @Harry надо константность убрать!

Comment: Рад, что вы поняли, о чем я...

Comment: Очень странный код. Обычно перемещаемые объекты - это подмножество копируемых. Например класс с перегруженными операциями копирования но без операций перемещения считается перемещаемым. Попытка переместить его вызовет копирование, но не будет ошибкой. Поэтому код можно заменить просто на `Data[Size] = std::move(value);`, без `if`-а.

Comment: В теории можно создать копируемый но не перемещаемый класс, определив копирующие операции и сделав `=delete` для перемещающих операций, но нормальные люди так не делают, и я бы это никак не обрабатывал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема в слове `const` - правда, в вопросе этого кода вы не привели -

```
void push_back(const T & value) {
    if constexpr (std::is_move_assignable<T>::value) {
        Data[Size] = std::move(value);
    } else {
        Data[Size] = value;
    }
```

Вы не можете перемещать *константный* объект... Вот так

```
void push_back(T & value) {
```

все заработает. А с `const`, естественно, компилятор недопустимый перемещающий оператор пытается заменить на копирующий.

Comment: А может `T&&` вместо `T&`?

Comment: @Qwertiy `void push_back(const T && value)` ? Это не спасет. А `void push_back(T && value) {` у него и так есть...

Comment: Я про второе. Его код не смотрел. А зачем нужен if если есть 2 перегрузки?

Comment: @Qwertiy Это уже второй вопрос :), и не ко мне...